# Inheritance. Call child class function from parent class

Tags: c++, oop, qt

```
class C1 {
    void A();
    void B();
}

void C1::A(){ return B(); }

class C2 : public C1 {
    void B();
}

C2 *obj = new C2;
obj->A(); // returns B() from C1
```

Why does B() from C1 called? How to make A() exist only in C1 and call B() from C2?

Comment: You don't need to write `()` after `C2` in `new C2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make `B()` in `C1` a [`virtual`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#C.2B.2B) function.

Virtual functions are basically function pointers that take their value upon initialization of the object. If you `new C1`, the function pointer would point to `C1::B` while if you `new C2` that function pointer would point to `C2::B`.

**Note:** To read more about `virtual` and related subjects, search for *function overriding* and *polymorphism*.

Answer (score 2):

Member methods are not `virtual` by default in C++ (do you come from Java)?

When you write:

```
class C1 {
    void A();
    void B();
}

class C2 : public C1 {
    void B();
}
```

you're not *overriding* `B()` in `C2`, but **hiding** it.

To override it, you must declare it `virtual` in the base class (**virtual** in subsequent classes is not necessary).